# floatrow destroys common solution for parallel figures

Tags: floats, floatrow

I really like the `floatrow` package, but when its code is not required I expect that everything works as normal, however the correct code fails to compile once `floatrow` is loaded.

What I am talking about are simple parallel `figure`s placed in `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}%
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/TestBild.png}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:figures:2}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{images/TestBild.png}
    \caption{Another figure}\label{fig:figures:3}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}%
```

Comment out `floatrow` and it compiles correctly.

Any possible solution to get it working with `floatrow` loaded but without any `floatrow` commands?

Comment: You could resort to using floatrow for parallel figures. After all consistency is a good practice (if you place figures with floatrow at some place in a document it would be consistent to make any other placement with floatrow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that one needs to restore the normal LaTeX behaviour, which is introduced by adding `\RawFloats` at the beginning of the figure environment.

Comment: ...and if you use it as `\csname RawFloats\endcsname` the code will even compile without `floatrow` package.